# compatibility issue is IE10

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, cross-browser

I have an asp.net website that looks good, as it should, on IE8,IE9 as well as the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.

the server click is working fine in all web browsers..
in IE10 it's not working..when Clicking IE10's "Compatibility button" its work fine..

but I can't tell all users to turn on compatibility button and browse.

I want to do dis in coding side..
I have tried
 `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >`

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

and this also

[try dis also](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx)

I've tried overriding the compatibility mode, to no avail:

but it's not working in IE10.

Comment: Clicking the compatibility button does more than merely using a different renderer. It also affects the request that gets sent to the web server, and the web server may return different data as a result of that. Can you verify that the HTML that gets sent to IE9 and IE10 is exactly the same?

Comment: Then you'll need to make sure the correct HTML gets sent to IE10 too. Only if it then still doesn't render as intended might X-UA-Compatible help.

Comment: tats what i am searching which html code have to send IE10?

Comment: ... You just said you weren't sending the same HTML as for IE9 and earlier. Send the same HTML that you send IE9, see how IE10 behaves then, and only after that look at whether you need to add X-UA-Compatible.

Comment: in ie9 its working fine without X-UA-Compatible but in ie10 its not working...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26149/discussion-between-user960439-and-hvd)

Comment: @EdGraham how did you solved the issue??

Comment: I think you should make sure that your markup/code is doing things properly. If you have to force that awful "compatibility mode" to make it work, something isn't being done right. Typically one would expect that good code works best on the latest browsers, and that the old browsers are the ones giving trouble. Why you're seeing different HTML sent from the server based on the different user agent, that I do not know.

Comment: I agree with jameh and would be interested in knowing what the document type declaration is that you are using.

Comment: @user960439 I didn't solve it, I'm afraid: instead I rewrote the code so that it looked good in IE10 and then added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1"> to the <head /> element.  Unhelpful, I know ...

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
<head runat="server">
<meta id="FirstCtrlID" runat="server" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

IE compatibility meta tags have been described in detail by this answer in the answer to the following question [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=9, IE=10, IE=Edge" />
```

here IE=Edge is to mean highest compatibility. but for your problem IE=10 will be the fix.